# What would happen to "The Knights of Ni" if King Arthur kept saying the word?

Tags: monty-python-holy-grail

Well the formerly called "Knights of Ni!" which are now called "The Knights of Ekke Ekke Ekke Ekke Ptang Zoo Boing!"

I have always wondered what would have happened if King Arthur kept of on saying the word,

> "It"

There are tons of interviews on "Monty Python and the Holy Grail", and rightly so, there is not much about what happened to the "The Knights of Ekke Ekke Ekke Ekke Ptang Zoo Boing!"

Any out of universe answers are very welcome.

Comment: More to the point, did they ever get the second shrubbery?

Comment: @Spencer, the first one was vandalized, but I am not sure the police were looking for the vandals. I know they were looking for the historians killer.